# How can I fetch the data in a single row

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am tying to fetch the data from firebase just like make single row of first element of all the headings in firebase database. i.e first element of Amount, key, time, total, Number should make a single row and then so on.

I am trying with foreach loop but I can refer to the correct refrence of firebase

```
//html code
<table style="width:100%" id="ex-table">
  <tr id="tr">
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Key</th> 
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>Total</th>

 </table> 


//Javascript code
var database = firebase.database();

database.ref().once('value', function(snapshot){
    if(snapshot.exists()){
        var content = '';
        snapshot.forEach(function(data){
            var val = data.val();
            content +='<tr>';
            content += '<td>' + val.Amount + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.Key + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.Number + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.Time + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.Total + '</td>';
            content += '</tr>';
        });
        $('#ex-table').append(content);
    }
});
```

I am getting undefined instead of values

[image]

[image: plz check my database picture]

Comment: Use the browser's developer console and use `console.log()` on the object. You need to learn how to *reverse-program* until you find the initial source or how far it gets so you can determine what the problem is specifically.

Comment: _"...help me fast urgent plz Beginner"_ - Such conduct (in the title) has at most the opposite effect...

Comment: @Andreas my bad